# Trying to make a custom report for osTicket

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a custom report (in a form of a time sheet from osTicket), I have been trying to work on this

```
SELECT body, created, project IN ("nw"), time-nwproject 
FROM ost_thread_entry, ost_ticket__cdata
WHERE ost_thread_entry.project = ost_ticket__cdata.project
```

The result was this

[image: example]

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: For what you're doing wrong, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Incidentally, the result of `project IN` could not be `'project' IN`, so you've got something wrong in your transcription.

Answer (score 1):

`project IN ("nw")` returns 1 or 0, if `project` is one of the items in the set. Based on the query, it will always return 0 (false).

Replace that part of the query with a SQL case expression or if function.

Is `nw` a table? Please provide your schema so that we can help you craft a query.

Use `project LIKE '%nw%` instead then.

Comment: The type is utf8_general_ci and no nw is part of the project field, bascilly im looking for a way to report if any projects have nw in them

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to check if the `project` column has 'nw' in it, then use `project LIKE '%nw%'` instead of `project IN ("nw")`.

Using table alias to remove ambiguity, with this query:

```
SELECT body, created, project, time-nwproject 
FROM ost_thread_entry, ost_ticket__cdata
WHERE ost_thread_entry.project = ost_ticket__cdata.project
AND ost_thread_entry.project LIKE '%nw%'
```

I don't know about the other columns. But prefix the column names with an alias or the full table name.

Comment: Unexpected token. (near "'%nw%, time-nwproject                               FROM ost_thread_entry, ost_ticket__cdata        WHERE ost_thread_entry.project = ost_ticket__cdata.project"" at position 35)

Comment: check your single quotes (') and make sure they match

Comment: Error
SQL query: Documentation


SELECT body, created, project, time-nwproject FROM ost_thread_entry, ost_ticket__cdata WHERE ost_thread_entry.project = ost_ticket__cdata.project AND project LIKE '%nw%' LIMIT 0, 25
MySQL said: Documentation

#1052 - Column 'project' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: *use an alias. I believe both tables ost_thread_entry and ost_ticket__cdata have a column project*. I will update the query.